# How to redirect user based on the user's role to different activities in android

Tags: android, authentication, android-activity, sharedpreferences, user-roles

I'm new to android development. I would like to create an app with at least 2 user roles. I want the users to be redirected to different activities after their login. I read that it is possible to do that using firebase, but I would not like to use it in my application, since I already started building the app and used retrofit and shared preferences so far. I also found another question her asking the same question and someone answered that it is possible to do so with sessionManager class.

Their answer was:

"Well, I would like to provide my own answer. I actually used `Shared Preferences`. Its much simple and could globally use the values we put in it. Below is the code:

**1. Create a separate class and name it as you wish(I prefer SessionManager here)**

```
public class SessionManager {

   // Shared Preferences
   SharedPreferences sharedPrefer;

   // Editor for Shared preferences
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

   // Context
   Context context;

   // Shared Pref mode
   int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

   // Shared Pref file name
   private static final String PREF_NAME = "MySession";

   // SHARED PREF KEYS FOR ALL DATA

   // User's UserId
   public static final String KEY_USERID = "userId";

   // User's categoryId
   public static final String KEY_CATID = "catId";

   // User's categoryType[Teacher, Student, etc.,]
   public static final String KEY_CATTYPE = "categoryType";

   // User's batchId[like class or level or batch]
   public static final String KEY_BATCHID = "batchId";



    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
       sharedPrefer = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
       editor = sharedPrefer.edit();
    }

/**
 * Call this method on/after login to store the details in session
 * */

   public void createLoginSession(String userId, String catId, String catTyp, String batchId) {        

       // Storing userId in pref
       editor.putString(KEY_USERID, userId);

       // Storing catId in pref
       editor.putString(KEY_CATID, catId);

       // Storing catType in pref
       editor.putString(KEY_CATTYPE, catTyp);

       // Storing catType in pref
       editor.putString(KEY_BATCHID, batchId);

       // commit changes
       editor.commit();
   }

/**
 * Call this method anywhere in the project to Get the stored session data
 * */
   public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {

       HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
       user.put("userId",sharedPrefer.getString(KEY_USERID, null));
       user.put("batchId",sharedPrefer.getString(KEY_BATCHID, null));      
       user.put("catId", sharedPrefer.getString(KEY_CATID, null));
       user.put("catType", sharedPrefer.getString(KEY_CATTYPE, null));

       return user;
   }
}
```

**2. Calling the above methods on some other classes inside the project:**

*Storing the data in session*

```
SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
session.createLoginSession(userId, categoryId, categoryType, batchId);
```

*Retrieving the data from session*

```
SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
String userId = user.get("userId").toString();
String categoryId = user.get("catId").toString();
String categoryType = user.get("catType").toString();
String batchId= user.get("batchId").toString();
```

" - @sam

I'm a bit confused with this answer. I understand the code, but I'm clueless on how could this be used to redirect the users to different activities. Any help and explanation on how to do so would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To set a Shared Preference use this code below:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("ID_NAME_EXAMPLE","STRING_TO_SAVE");
editor.apply();
```

To access the Shared Preference use this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String name = preferences.getString("ID_NAME_EXAMPLE", "DEFAULT_VALUE_IF_NONE");
```

So for example you can have a `Shared Preference` saved as `WHICH_ACTIVITY`

```
editor.putString("WHICH_ACTIVITY","one");
editor.apply();
```

Then accesses it when user signs in as

```
String name = preferences.getString("WHICH_ACTIVITY", "zero");
if(name.equals("zero")){
    startActivity(0);
}
else if(name.equals("one")){
    startActivity(1);
}
```